# Accessing task completion status in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint, win32com

I am trying to produce an application (in Python, as it happens, though using COM objects as in VBA) to export a PowerPoint presentation to a video. This is easily done using the `SaveAs` method, as in

```py
pres.SaveAs("some/output/directory",ppSaveAsMP4)
```

which is fine, though I'm not sure how to finish up, as if you try to call `pres.Close()` and `app.Quit()` the video export is cancelled. Is there a function that returns the completion status of the export task (it's displayed on the progress bar, though I know that isn't exposed on the Object model)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to poll the presentation's CreateVideoStatus property.

Possible return values:

```
0 None (nothing being processed, I'd assume)
1 In Progress
2 Queued
3 Done
4 Failed
```

Pro forma link to Microsoft's "help" on this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/PowerPoint.Presentation.CreateVideoStatus
I'll buy you a beer if you can find anything useful in it.